# Pyspark : How can create the columns in dataframe with differents condition

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I want to create to column in Pyspark with two differents condidtions and one dataframe :  df = dataframe[col1, col2] where

col1 = join df_A with df_B based on df_A::MTAV = df_B::CODE

col2 = join df_A with df_B based on df_A::MTAP = df_B::CODE

How can create two columns in a datframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not mentioned the logic that you need for col1 and col2 here. you can implement the logic like below, have the join implemented in two different dataframes then join both new dataframes with new columns together.

```
df_mtav = (df_a
           .join(df_b, df_a.mtav == df_b.code)
           .withColumn("mtav_col", <column logic here>)
          )

df_mtap = (df_a
           .join(df_b, df_a.mtap == df_b.code)
           .withColumn("mtap_col", <column logic here>)
          )

df_final = (df_mtav
            .join(df_mtap, df_mtap.code == df_mtav.code)
           )
```